# How to update Mountain Lion 10.8 to Catalina OS?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, catalina

I had Catalina OS on my Macbook, but I was needed to reinstall OS. So I make a restart hold Command + R (Mac utility was opened), so I erase all data and reinstall OS. But when I reinstall OS, there is was not choice which OS I would like to install and Mountain Lion 10.8 was installed.

Now, I would like to upgrade this OS version to Catalina like it was before...

But I can't, I get message from AppStore that I need to have 10.9 OS version or  later.

So, as far as I understand I need to install any intermediate OS version like El Captain or Mavericks and just than get update to Catalina, right?

But issue is, that Mavericks no longer supported by AppStore , but I found link to El Captain, but I also got a message that this version can't be installed...

What to do? How can I get update?

Feel free to ask

Comment: Basically, you need the special version of El Capitan first, mentioned lower down the answer, but read the note at the top about expired certificates.

Comment: @Tetsujin But I don't get message that my certificate was expired I get this message `This version of OS X 10.11 cannot be installed on this computer.` when I try to get El captain from App Store... Maybe because of that in app store is update for El Captain, but not the installer of the OS...

Comment: So, eventually I updated OS to El Captain (according to this tutorial https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT206886), and just after this I had an option to update to Catalina (from AppStore)